# Citation without printing references at the end of document

Tags: bibliographies

How I can use the ".bib" file in such a way that it does not print References at the end..

Comment: With `biblatex` you simply don't add `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I am using only these two statements \bibliographystyle{apacite} \bibliography{Bibliography2}.. I am not using \printbibliogrphy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{Bibliography2}}}
```

Comment: There is no need for [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) here...